# Can't access post route from API callback

Tags: php, laravel, api

I use a webhook to receive callback post from an API server. I've tested to post data from postman, it's works fine but from API server i can't receive anything. 
But when i changed webhook by using webhook.site, it's work, but with my domain webhook its not, didn't even access my post route.
My route:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Web'], function () {  
//Callback card
Route::post('/callback', 'CustomersController@callbackCard');
```

My Controller:(If accessed post route will store a file)

```
public function callbackCard(Request $request){
    Storage::put('Accessed.txt', '1');


}
```

Sorry for my bad English
Can anyboy help me.

Comment: Which API you are using?

Comment: show your url!! and are you using the `Web` as prefix??

Answer (score 0):

the callback API just send Post with application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
my url: domain/callback
default namespace Web